# flex css - clip elements after certain height instead of wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: flex default behavior]

The border represents the static heights and widths.

I want Item five and item six to stay in the second row and have item three and six clipped instead of wrapping the third time as shown in the picture. How can I achieve this through flex?

To add to this question, the width of the container (shown with the border) is resizable by user action. when it is wide. For example, if it is wide enough to fit 4 elements, it will show all 4 in the first row, and the rest in the second row.

When we collapse the width of the container, I want it to have a maximum of 2 rows and show as the picture below.

I want the outcome to look like this for visualization:

[[image]]

https://codepen.io/akeni/pen/LYBGOXB

```
<div id="example-element" class="transition-all" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <div>Item One</div>
        <div>Item Two</div>
        <div>Item Three</div>
        <div>Item Four</div>
        <div>Item Five</div>
        <div>Item Six</div>
</div>


#example-element {
    border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#example-element > div {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
    border: 3px solid #00f;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand completely what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate a little more and add some code? Thanks.

In other hands, Im pretty sure the properties you need are 'max-width' (to prevent the item from overgrowing), ['wrap: no-wrap'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) to prevent flex items from jumping to the next row and another option is to use 'overflow: hidden' to hide the extra content.

But, like I sayd, I need more details to be able to provide a more exact answer. ;)

Comment: Hi, I've added some more information :)

Answer (score 1):

Its a little bit confusing calling a flex container "element". I personally prefer to call them "blabla-container", where 'blabla' is waterver I'm working with in that section (for example: "nav-links-container". But that of course is just a matter of taste.

About the question, thanks for the new info, if you are open to suggestions, the easiest way to do it is with css-grid:

```css
#example-element {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    /* or this way: 
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    */   
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

You can find more detailed info here: [MDN Docs, css-grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids#flexible_grids_with_the_fr_unit)

Ahh and one more detail, what you call "clipping", happens when the parent container is not big enought to contain the children with fixed sizes, so if after applying this changes you don't see it behaving as in the second picture, simply make the parent component smaller (200px for example) and voila!

Comment: Hi, this is really close to what I was trying to achieve. I'm missing one puzzle piece as I realized that I left some details of how the parent container behaves

Answer (score 0):

Grid layout would be easier here, as you want to show specific numbers of columns per row.

Use `grid-template-columns` to specify how many columns you want and their width. Then use `overflow: hidden` to hide those overflowed elements.

```css
#example-element {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
    gap: 1rem;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#example-element > div {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.2);
    border: 3px solid #00f;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="example-element" class="transition-all" style="flex-wrap: wrap;">
        <div>Item One</div>
        <div>Item Two</div>
        <div>Item Three</div>
        <div>Item Four</div>
        <div>Item Five</div>
        <div>Item Six</div>
</div>
```